# Expectation of minimum with exponential distributions

Tags: probability-theory, exponential-function, maxima-minima, exponential-distribution, expected-value

Suppose $t_i$ is a random variable with exponential distribution. Let $M$ be a fixed real number. My instructor says $$E[min\{t_i, M\}]=E[t_i]-E[t_i]\times P(t_i >M).$$ I am a little confused. If this is indeed true, then $$E[min\{t_i, M\}]=E[t_i]\times P(t_i \leq M).$$ How should we think about it? Any thoughts or comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$,\begin{align}
E[\min\{ T, M\}] & = \int_0^\infty f(t) \min\{t,M \} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^M f(t) t \, dt + \int_M^\infty Mf(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty f(t) t \, dt - \int_M^\infty f(t) t \, dt  + \int_M^\infty Mf(t) \, dt\\
&= E[T] - \int_M^\infty f(t) (t-M) \, dt \\
&= E[T] - \int_0^\infty v\lambda \exp(-\lambda(v+M) )  \, dv \\
&= E[T] -  \exp(-\lambda M)\int_0^\infty v\lambda \exp(-\lambda v )  \, dv \\
&= E[T] -  \exp(-\lambda M)E[T] \\
&= E[T] -  E[T] Pr(T >M)\\
\end{align}